# Failure Message: "System.QueryException: No such column 'Address' on entity 'Lead'. I

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

> I am passing all test coverage in salesforce  apex in sandbox but in deploying to live getting the
>   error in subject, i dont know how to handle it.
>        my test class code is:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class myLeadTest{ 

 public static testMethod void testMyController5() {

                Account acc= new Account(name='test');
                acc.Order__c='wee';
                insert acc;

                Campaign camp = new Campaign(Name='test');
                insert camp;

                Company__c cm= new Company__c();
                cm.Company_Id__c=12;
                cm.Name='234';
                cm.Account__c=acc.id;
                insert cm;


                Lead l= new Lead();
                l.Campaign__c=camp.Id;
                l.LastName='test';
                l.Company='cmpny';
                l.Company_Id__c=cm.Company_Id__c;
                l.Email='test@yahoo.com';
                l.Status='Closed - Converted';


                l.Order__c=acc.Order__c;


               // l.Auto_Convert__c=true;
               // l.IsConverted=false;

                //l.ConvertedAccountId=acc.Id;
                Lead[] l2= new Lead[]{l};
                insert l2;

                Opportunity op= new Opportunity ();
                op.StageName='Won (Agency)';
                op.Name='test';
                op.CloseDate=Date.valueOf('2015-04-28');
                op.AccountId=acc.id;
                op.LeadSource='web';
                op.StageName= 'Won (Agency)';
                op.CampaignId=camp.id;
                op.TrialStart__c=Date.valueOf('2012-04-28');  
                insert op;

                Contact cnt= new Contact();
                cnt.LastName='test';
                cnt.AccountId=acc.id;
                cnt.ASEO_Company_Id__c=12;
                cnt.Email=l.Email;
                cnt.Company__c=cm.id;
                insert cnt;

                ///////////////
            /*    Lead l5= new Lead();
                l5.Campaign__c=camp.Id;
                l5.LastName='test';
                l5.Company='cmpny';
                l5.Company_Id__c=12;
                l5.Email='test@yahoo.com';
                l5.Status='Closed-Converted';
                l5.isConverted=false;
                //l.ConvertedAccountId=acc.Id;              
                insert l5; */
                Contact cnt1= new Contact(); 
                cnt1.LastName='test';
                cnt1.AccountId=acc.id;
                cnt1.ASEO_Company_Id__c=12;
                cnt1.Email=l.Email;  
                insert cnt1;                
                Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
                  leadConvert.setLeadId(l2[0].Id);
                  LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
                  leadConvert.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
                  leadConvert.setOpportunityName(op.Name);
                  leadConvert.setConvertedStatus('Closed - Converted');
                  Database.LeadConvertResult lcResult = Database.ConvertLead(leadConvert);
                //  MyLead.addCampaign(l2[0], camp.Name);
                //  MyLead.updateOpportunity(l2[0], lcResult);

              //   MyLead.updateContact( l2[0], lcResult, cm) ;            
               //  myLead.addCampaignMembers(l2);


                }

}
```

> and class code which i call in trigger :

```
public class MyLead {
    public static void convertLead(Lead[] leads) {
      Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
      for (Lead lead :leads) {
        if (!(lead.IsConverted)) {
          // Check if an account exists with email. Attach Contact and Account, convert Lead.
          Contact[] myContacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = :lead.Email Limit 1];
          if (myContacts.size() == 1) {
            System.debug('Existing Contact');
            MyLead.attachExistingConvert(lead, myContacts[0]);
          }
          else {
            System.debug('No existing contact');
            if (lead.Auto_Convert__c) {

             MyLead.addCampaign(lead, lead.Campaign__c);

              leadConvert.setLeadId(lead.Id);
              leadConvert.setConvertedStatus('Closed - Converted');
              Database.LeadConvertResult lcResult = Database.ConvertLead(leadConvert);

              // Populate the newly created records with extra data.
              MyLead.updateOpportunity(lead, lcResult);
              Company__c myCompany = [SELECT Id FROM Company__c WHERE Company_Id__c = :lead.Company_Id__c];
              MyLead.updateContact(lead, lcResult, myCompany);
              // Must update the Company before Account otherwise the Account lookup will fail.
              MyLead.updateCompany(lead, lcResult, myCompany);
              MyLead.updateAccount(lead, lcResult, myCompany);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Attaches Lead to Contact and Account if matched by Email, converts Lead and creates opportunity if it doesn't exist.
    public static void attachExistingConvert(Lead lead, Contact contact) {
        MyLead.addCampaign(lead, lead.Campaign__c);
        Database.leadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        leadConvert.setLeadId(lead.Id);
        leadConvert.setConvertedStatus('Closed - Converted');
        leadConvert.setContactId(contact.Id);
        leadConvert.setAccountId(contact.AccountId);
        leadConvert.setSendNotificationEmail(True);
        // Do not create an opportunity if any exist.
        Opportunity[] myOpportunity = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :contact.AccountId];
        if (myOpportunity.size() > 0) {
          leadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
        }
        leadConvert.setLeadId(lead.Id);
        Database.LeadConvertResult leadConvertResult = Database.convertLead(leadConvert);
        // If we created an opportunity, update it with extra stuff.
        if (leadConvert.isDoNotCreateOpportunity() == False) {
          MyLead.updateOpportunity(lead, leadConvertResult);
        }
    }

    // Updates the newly created Opportunity with extra data
    public static void updateOpportunity(Lead lead, Database.LeadConvertResult lcResult) {
      Opportunity myOpportunity = [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :lcResult.opportunityId];
      myOpportunity.Name = 'Online Upgrade';
      myOpportunity.TrialStart__c = lead.CreatedDate.date();
      //myOpportunity.Amount = lead.Monthly_Revenue__c;
      myOpportunity.Amount = lead.Amount__c;
      myOpportunity.Type = 'New Business';
      myOpportunity.LeadSource = 'Website';
      myOpportunity.Order__c = lead.Order__c;
      DateTime dt = System.now();
      Date d = dt.date(); 
      myOpportunity.CloseDate = d;
      myOpportunity.StageName = lead.Agency__c ? 'Won (Agency)' : 'Won (End User)';
      myOpportunity.Probability = 100;

      update myOpportunity;
    }

    // Updates the newly created Account with extra data 
    public static void updateAccount(Lead lead, Database.LeadConvertResult lcResult, Company__c myCompany) {
      Account myAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :lcResult.accountId];
      myAccount.Type = 'Customer';
      myAccount.ASEO_Company_Id__c = lead.Company_Id__c;
      myAccount.Company__c = myCompany.Id; // Setting the company will cause the company account lookup to fail
      myAccount.Order__c = lead.Order__c;

      update myAccount;
    }

    // Updates the newly created Contact with extra data 
    public static void updateContact(Lead lead, Database.LeadConvertResult lcResult, Company__c myCompany) {
      Contact myContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id = :lcResult.contactId];
      myContact.ASEO_Company_Id__c = lead.Company_Id__c;
      myContact.Company__c = myCompany.Id;

      update myContact;
    }

    // Updates the Company with extra data 
    public static void updateCompany(Lead lead, Database.LeadConvertResult lcResult, Company__c myCompany) {
      myCompany.Account__c = lcResult.accountId;

      update myCompany;
    }

    // Adds a lead to a campaign
    public static void addCampaign(Lead lead, String campaign) {

      Campaign[] myCampaigns = [Select Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name = :campaign LIMIT 1];
      if (myCampaigns.size() == 1) {
        CampaignMember campaignMember = new CampaignMember (campaignId=myCampaigns[0].Id, leadId=lead.Id);
        insert campaignMember;
      }
    }
    // Create campaign members from leads. Campaign comes from lead.Campaign__c.
    public static void addCampaignMembers(Lead[] leads) {
      for (Lead lead :leads) {
        // Might want to query Campaigns table instead.
        //Set<String> campaigns = new Set<String>();
        //campaigns.add('Freemium');
        Campaign[] myCampaigns = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name = :lead.Campaign__c LIMIT 1];

        //if (campaigns.contains(lead.Campaign__c)) {
        if (myCampaigns.size() == 1) {
          MyLead.addCampaign(lead, lead.Campaign__c);
        }
      }
     } 

}
```

> and my lead trigger is:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    Lead[] leads = Trigger.new;
    //MyLead.createOpportunity(leads);
    MyLead.convertLead(leads);

Please any one can help me, i tries 25 times but in deploying to production  give me error in the given subject, or any one give code coverage of this class,  thank you in advance
```

Comment: Riaz, from your comment to Christian it sounds like you solved your problem. Best is to post an answer to your own question and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is based on a soql query that is not included in your code. You try to query a field called "Address" but this field doesn't exist. Address is still in beta...

Try to adjust your query and use the fields City, Street, Country and PostalCode.

You can learn more about sObject fields there: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm

Comment: ok thanks but it was conflict with an install package on live side, as i uninstall that package and try it again, i got success and deployed

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else get to this question with this problem.

As Christian said, the code is trying to access the "Address" field from Lead in a SOQL query. Starting from API version 30, the compound fields are available to use in queries (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/compound_fields_address.htm).

So, if you run into this issue with a query in your code, check for the API version of the class and the visualforce page. Both must be 30 or greater.